# Jquery Mobile's checkboxes change firing twice with phonegap on iOS (but working on Android)

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using checkboxes in my JQM/Phonegap Build app.

```
<div id="wavetypes" class=ui-grid-b>
                    <div class=ui-block-a>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-t-2a" id="wavetypes_checkboxsmallwave" data-theme="b">
                        <label for="wavetypes_checkboxsmallwave">Small-wave</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class=ui-block-b>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-t-2b" id="wavetypes_checkboxperf" data-theme="b">
                        <label for="wavetypes_checkboxperf">Performance</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class=ui-block-c>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-t-2c" id="wavetypes_checkboxstepup" data-theme="b">
                        <label for="wavetypes_checkboxstepup">Step-up</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And I am listening to their change like this

```
$(document).on('pagecreate','#welcome-page', function(){    

$(document).on('change','#wavetypes_checkboxsmallwave, #wavetypes_checkboxperf, #wavetypes_checkboxstepup',function(){ 

    console.log('-------------------');
    console.log(e.target.tagName.toUpperCase()+' : ' + $(this).attr('id') +', is checked ? : '+$(this).is(":checked"));
    if (e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() === "LABEL") {
        return;
    }
        var proId = $('#chosenpro').find(":selected").val();
        var brandid = $('#chosenbrand').find(":selected").val();
        console.log(proId);
        console.log(brandid);
        if ( !$.isNumeric(proId) ) {
            console.log("proId is not numeric");
            if ( !$.isNumeric(brandid) ) {
                console.log("brandid is not numeric");
                //resetModelsListView(prodata, false, 0, 0, 0);
                //addBoardAndLogoInModelListView();

            } else {
                var targetbrand = prodata[brandid]['brand'];
                //resetModelsListView(prodata, false, 0, targetbrand, 0);
                //addBoardAndLogoInModelListView();
            }
        } else {
            console.log("proId IS numeric");
            var targetproName = prodata[proId]['name'];
            var targetbrand = prodata[brandid]['brand'];

            //LISTVIEW
            //resetModelsListView(prodata, false, 0, targetbrand, targetproName);
            //addBoardAndLogoInModelListView();
        }
    });
```

...but the boxes don't get checked when I tap on them on Phonegap + iOS.

It works well on desktop or on Phonegap + Android.

Can you help please ?

edit: it seems that the js is being bound twice... so the checkbox checks and unchecks....but I can't figure out why...

edit:
the event is fired twice on iOS, here's the console ouput (it gets checked then unchecked...weird !!) :

```
-------------------
INPUT : checkboxperf, is checked ? : true
-------------------
INPUT : checkboxperf, is checked ? : false
```

Comment: Try commenting out resetModelsListView(...) and addBoardAndLogoInModelListView(). Narrow down which one is causing the problem and then if you cannot figure out the issue, show us the code in the function causing the problem.

Comment: Hi @ezanker, I just tried this, and the issue stays the same. However I am noting, that if I tap several times (5 times or so) on a checkbox it finally starts to react and becomes checkable and unchekable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in jQuery Mobile. I worked around it by preventing the default behavior of the click and toggling the the inputs checked value manually:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-checkbox', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    var $checkboxInput = $(this).find('input');
    var isChecked = $checkboxInput.is(':checked');
    $checkboxInput.attr('checked', !isChecked).checkboxradio('refresh');

    // do your stuff
});
```

I tested this in JSFiddle (Chrome) and iPhone 4S (iOS 8.1). This solution doesn't seem to work in browser but in my Phonegap app for iOS it does. This indicates that it may not work on other platforms either.

If you are targeting for multiple platforms, I recommend you use your old handler for those and make a function of the code inside your handler.

Comment: Hi @balzafin good idea thanks, but I see that even with your fix, the event is run twice (I edited my question see the console output please...)

Comment: Ok. If you can't find out why the event is triggered twice, you can try to work around it by using `.off()` to unbind the event before binding it again. It would be more simple, if you added a common class to your checkboxes, lets say `.checkbox`. Something like this: `$(document).off("change", ".checkbox").on("change", ".checkbox", function () {//...});`.

Comment: Hi @balsafin, even with this .off and .on, the event is fired twice... I am going crazy with this !

Comment: This is very strange. Have you tested if `click` event on the check boxes fires also twice or is it only `change`? I was thinking that maybe you could prevent the default behavior of `change` and use `click` to toggle the checked value of the input manually.

Comment: To specify, try to prevent the default behavior on .ui-checkbox: `$(document).on('change click', '.ui-checkbox', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
});`

Comment: I finally got to debug this with iPhone and was able to reproduce the behavior you described. I found away around it and edited my answer.

Comment: Hey @balzafin, thanks A LOT ! This works. Should we signal the bug to JQM devs ?

Comment: You're welcome. I will try to dig deeper into this when I have time because this is a very strange bug. It's amazing no one has reported this before. This may be PhoneGap + jQuery Mobile 1.4.x grouped checkboxes + iOS bug only. Single checkbox seems to have no problems like this. PhoneGap Build could also be a factor. Grouped checkboxes used to work with jQM 1.3. I know it because I used them on my app.

Comment: ok, indeed, it must be a bug for these conditions only...it is weird indeed. That's great that you helped me with this. You seem weel aware of JQM + Phonegap settting. These check box are really (really slow) on iOS, do you think you can help me find a way to make them quicker ? Also, I posted a question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740999/jquery-mobile-phonegap-improve-listview-performance  regarding performance of the list that is controlled by those filter checkboxes you helped on. Do you think you can help me on this too ?   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and addressed it by removing the "for" attribute on "label" element.

My elements were nested as follows:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="opt1" data-mini="true" data-iconpos="right">Option label here</label>
```

Guessing  it's a bug in jQuery Mobile 1.4.5 (with jQuery 1.11.1). It didn't matter if the checkbox was grouped or single in my case.

Answer (score 0):

a couple of hints...

I've had lots of trouble with the event listener construct you're using, so instead I just do:

`$('#welcome-page').on('pagecreate') function...`

As a matter of course even though it's not always necessary, I turn "off" event listeners before I turn them on. This helps keep me from binding many times to a single event.

`$('#welcome-page'.off('pagecreate');
$('#welcome-page'.on('pagecreate') function...`

Comment: Thanks but, I've never had any troubles with this....I don't think it is the problem